# Is there a FICS client for Android?

Tags: online-chess

Is there an Android client for the Free Internet Chess Server (FICS)?

Comment: Yafi ( https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.mg6.yafi ) has a very positive rating at the Google store. I just tried out the free version on my Android tablet, and it worked very nicely. The ads (which a paid version removes) weren't intrusive at all either. So it gets a thumbs up from me too.

Comment: Anna, I'm going to close this particular question, since the info you're after is readily googleable (and there's a list of Android clients at the FICS site, including the one I mentioned). I do hope you'll return with more questions though :)

Comment: Best Android client for FICS is [Mobialia Chess](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alonsoruibal.chessdroid.lite&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5hbG9uc29ydWliYWwuY2hlc3Nkcm9pZC5saXRlIl0.). It allows to see the seeks, observe games, watch tutorials by LectureBot, and even shortcuts to observe highest rated blitz/standard game.

Comment: ... and this question is applicable to the worldwide audience. Not sure why it is closed.